# How do I create user "groups" in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to make an app where each group will have admin and manager.
Currently, there is custom claims for admin and manager.
But I want something like this:

```
group1 {
    admin
    manager
}
group2 {
    admin
    manager
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can adapt your custom claims to `group1Admin` and `group1Manager` and similar for group 2

Comment: Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access.
Basically you cannot have custom user data in Firebase auth so you'll need to store your role related info in Firestore or Realtime Database.

Comment: It would help to know which Firebase product you're using - the Real Time Database or Could Firestore and the approach may be different. Also, a lot of how your database is structured depends on what you want to get out of it - suggesting a specific model without understanding how the data will be used may lead you down the wrong path, so just keep that in mind.